# Hierarchy in SQL Server - multiple levels

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, loops, hierarchical

I have the following requirement,

Input

```
ID Parent_ID
------------
1  0
2  0
3  10
4  0
5  3
6  20
7  3
8  21
9  3
10  0
20  0
21  0
```

- When I use `@ID = 1` the result has to be 1.
- When I use `@ID = 6` the result has to be 20.
- When I use `@ID = 5` or 7, 9 the result has to be 10, because 5 -> 3 (Parent_ID -> Str_ID) -> 10 (Parent_ID -> Str_ID) -> 0 (stop is 0 in Parent_ID), so the result 10.

So my task is looking for ID as long as I'll find 0 in `Parent_ID`.

Output:

```
@ID Result
----------
1  1
2  2 
3  10
4  4
5  10
6  20
7  10
8  21
9  10
10 10
20 20
21 21
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recursive CTE with rollup can do this: [MSDN Article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
BEGIN
--Setup some data
DECLARE @tmp as TABLE (ID int, ParentID int);
INSERT INTO @tmp
VALUES 
(1 , 0 ),
(2 , 0 ),
(3 , 10),
(4 , 0 ),
(5 , 3 ),
(6 , 20),
(7 , 3 ),
(8 , 21),
(9 , 3 ),
(10,  0),
(20,  0),
(21,  0),
(44,  5),
(83,  44),
(46,  83),
(23,  7);

WITH Parents (ID, ParentID, TopParent) AS (
    SELECT ID, ParentID, ID
        FROM @tmp
        WHERE ParentID = 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT t.ID, t.ParentID, p.TopParent
        FROM Parents p 
        JOIN @tmp t on t.ParentID = p.id)
SELECT * FROM Parents
--Or to get just the ID and top parent: SELECT ID, TopParent FROM Parents 

END
```

Results:

```
ID          ParentID    TopParent
----------- ----------- -----------
1           0           1
2           0           2
4           0           4
10          0           10
20          0           20
21          0           21
8           21          21
6           20          20
3           10          10
5           3           10
7           3           10
9           3           10
23          7           10
44          5           10
83          44          10
46          83          10
```